# Using alias with Array operator in spring data mongo for the merge Object operation

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to convert mongo pipeline query to spring data mongo. Below is the sample pipeline which i am converting

```
{ 
  $addFields: { 
    orders:{ 
      $map: {
          input: "$orders", 
          as: "order", 
          in: { 
              $mergeObjects: [ 
                "$$order", 
              { 
                instance: { 
                  $first: { 
                      $filter: { 
                      input: "$instances", 
                      as: "instance", 
                      cond: { 
                        $eq: [ "$$order.instance.docKey", "$$instance._id", 
                         ], 
                      }, 
                        
                      }, 
                      
                    }
                },
              }, 
              ],
            }, 
        }, 
    }, 
 }
}
```

and below is the code that i have tried just cant figure out a way to give alias to object returned by first operator i.e. (instance: { ....)

```
       AddFieldsOperation addInstanceFieldOp = 
Aggregation.addFields() 
.addFieldWithValue("orders",mapItemsOf("orders")
    .as("order") 
.andApply(ObjectOperators. MergeObjects .mergeValuesOf("order") 
.mergeWithValuesOf( ArrayOperators.First.first( filter("instances") .as("instance") 
.by( ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("order.instance.docKey") .equalTo("instance._id") )) ) )).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue using PropertyExpression

below is the code for reference

```
   AddFieldsOperation addInstanceFieldOp = Aggregation.addFields() 
    .addFieldWithValue("orders" , mapItemsOf("orders") .as("orderArr") 
    .andApply(ObjectOperators. MergeObjects .mergeValuesOf("orderArr") .mergeWithValuesOf( 
    ArrayOperators.Reduce.PropertyExpression.property("instance")
.definedAs( ArrayOperators.First.first( filter("instances") 
    .as("instances") .by( ComparisonOperators.Eq.
valueOf("orderArr.instance.docKey") .equalTo("instances._id") )) )) ) ).build();
```